# Authenticate screen xcode 5 ios 7

Tags: ios, core-data, authentication

I am new in ios and I am stuck for days about how to make a login screen and let the user connect to the application.

Can anyone help me or give me a tutorial because I'm searching for days without finding anything. I am getting my user from a web service.

```
-(void)listeDesUtilisateurs{

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://127.0.0.1:8888/services/user.php" parameters:nil

     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {

     NSLog(@"JSON out : %@",responseObject);

     userTab = (NSArray *) [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"items"];

     NSLog(@"nombre des elements : %d", userTab.count );

     for (User *user in userMutTab) {
         [user.managedObjectContext deleteObject:user];
     }

     [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];



     for (int i=0; i<userTab.count; i++) {


         User *user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User"
                                                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


         NSDictionary *consultationDic = [userTab objectAtIndex:i];


         user.nom_utilisateur = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"username"];
         user.mot_de_passe = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"password"];
         user.nom_prenom = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"nom_prenom"];
         user.nom_prenom_en_arabe = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"nom_prenom_arabe"];
         user.specialite = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"specialite"];
         user.specialite_en_arabe = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"specialite_en_arabe"];
         user.gsm =[consultationDic objectForKey:@"gsm"];
         user.telephone_cabinet = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"telephone_cabinet"];
         user.adresse = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"adresse"];
         user.adresse_en_arabe =[consultationDic objectForKey:@"adresse_arabe"];

     }



     NSError *error;
     if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
     {
         NSLog(@"Problème d'enregistrement : %@",[error localizedDescription ] );
     }



 }

     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {

     NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error"
                                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",error]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];
 }];

 }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What are those if thats the case? Also, seems like you are using JSON. Google "AFJSONRequestOperation example" and many answers will come to your lap!

Comment: im storing the data in the core data what i whant is to make authentification page i don't know how :/